# Why is the height different on 2 elements on phones with the same pixel ratio?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm creating a react-native app and I'm confused how point values differ between phones. I've confirmed that an iPhone 8 and an iPhone 11 both have a pixel density of 2 [(Apple list of device screen sizes and pixel densities)](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/) and that Expo expects the same. [(Expo PixelRatio docs)](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/pixelratio/#getpixelsizeforlayoutsize)

However, if I create a View element and give it a height of 400 on an iPhone 8 and an iPhone 11 they are clearly different sizes. Why is this is the case?

A code example is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, PixelRatio} from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const TestComponent = () => {
  console.log('Device.modelName is: ', Device.modelName, 'Pixel ratio.get is: ', PixelRatio.get(), 'getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(400)', PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(400), 'getFontScale', PixelRatio.getFontScale());
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', height: 400}}></View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  }
)
```

As expected my console is logging:

Device.modelName is:  iPhone 8 Pixel ratio.get is:  2 getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(400) 800 getFontScale 1

Device.modelName is:  iPhone 11 Pixel ratio.get is:  2 getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(400) 800 getFontScale 1

But the element is clearly taller on the iPhone 8

[image]

Comment: The units of height and width in React Native aren't pixels, they're density independent pixels. Which is more about trying to keep things roughly the same physical size. Maybe that's where the discrepancy is?

Comment: Well, these simulators are resizable, so you might have them at not the exact sizes. Also I think iPhone 11 has more pixel density than 8 (not sure though)

Answer (score 0):

When I selected each phone and clicked on window -> physical size the height of the elements became the same on each phone.

I'm not sure why it wasn't working before. Maybe there's something odd about the default settings that affects the pixel ratio or I made a change I don't remember.